# Change the name of the Excel file created to date

Tags: excel, save, apache-poi

I wrote a program in which a list is converted into an Excel file. My Excel file contains the data of the list and its creation date. Now, I want the name of the file stored in the memory to be the same as its creation date. Please help me.

I'm using POI apache to create the Excel file.

```
File fileOutput = new File(storageVolume.getDirectory().getPath() + "/Download/BarcodeListt.xls");
public void buttonCreateExcelFile(View view) {
    HSSFWorkbook hssfWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFWorkbook datebook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet hssfSheet = hssfWorkbook.createSheet("BarcodeSheet");
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.getCount(); i++) {
      HSSFRow hssfRow = hssfSheet.createRow(i);
      HSSFCell hssfCell = hssfRow.createCell(0);
      hssfCell.setCellValue(list1.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
      HSSFCell hssfCellDate = hssfRow.createCell(2);
      hssfCellDate.setCellValue(ldt.format(FOMATTER));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ALL")
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
        Button scanBtn, btnok;
        ListView list1;
        TextView messageFormat, ragham;
        ArrayList < String > barcodelist = new ArrayList < > ();
        HashSet < String > hashSet = new HashSet < String > ();
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
        // String Bname =String.valueOf(ldt.getMinute());
        DateTimeFormatter FOMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a");
        String output = FOMATTER.format(LocalDateTime.now());
        String Filename = output;
```